# Does NPgsql provide support for OLEDB connection to PostgreSQL Server?

Tags: postgresql, oledb, npgsql

Is it possible to use NPgsql library and connect to PostgreSQL server through OLEDB provider?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: That is our requirement

Comment: If NPgsql does not support OLEDB provider, we will have to use some other library to connect to PostgreSQL through C#.net. But OLEDB provider is mandatory!

Comment: Npgsql connects to PostgreSQL, not a provider. Npgsql **is** a provider. Perhaps you don't understand the architecture. But it is hard to help you, because you don't tell us anything.